# Message integrity in TLS/SSL

Tags: openssl, security, ssl

I was reading about TLS/SSL protocol. There is two important points that are stopping me from proceeding further.

1) What is the need for maintaining message integrity in TLS/SSL. If server is always authenticated and there is a private channel established between client and server (thereby ruling out Man in the middle attack), how can someone modify the message in transit?

2) Even if there is a need to maintain integrity check, which hash function will be used? When is this contract established between client and server?

Any relevant reading links will be of great help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because you can't guarantee that there is a private channel in all situations - e.g. someone could control one of the many routing points between two hosts over the internet and perform an MitM attack.
2. The hash function is decided during the handshake. It is usually a HMAC version of a relatively strong hash function, e.g. an SHA2 family or Whirlpool.

The description of the [TLS protocol handshake on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake_in_detail) is very detailed and should help you understand how the cipher, hash function and other parameters are selected.

Comment: Polynomial, thanks for quick response. From point #1, I understand that we are trying to protect changes to the message that can occur in the underlying layers like IP or data link layer, correct? So only participants in the connection like routers, switches can be a part of malicious attack?

Comment: @Gopal - Somewhat, yes. Once your data is encrypted you must assume that every point from the physical NIC in your computer to the physical NIC in the server is in enemy terratory. It is possible for someone to, for example, perform ARP poisoning to cause themselves to be seen as your default gateway, thus constituting a man-in-the-middle attack. They could also root your switches or the switches of your ISP. There are even attacks involving electromagnetic induction which make it possible to alter data streams in transit through cables, though it's an unlikely scenario. Still, stay paranoid!